# How to handle spoiling user not correcting the syntax of the reply?

Tags: discussion

In [this reply](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/27739/4319) a user doesn't obey the non-spoiler policy. I've asked him to reformat and suggested a way to do so but last time I checked, he didn't.

How should I proceed (other than flagging and asking here) if I'm not prone to go in and rewrite that for him?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no policy regarding use of spoilers.  The general practice on the site seems to be to use spoilers to hide answers, but there is nothing *requiring* users to do so.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I wasn't aware of that. Well, common sense suggests that there should be such requirement, in my opinion. Frankly speaking, I'm surprised that it doesn't seem more obvious to the community.

Comment: I think there's been some controversy because spoilers are not heavily used on other SE sites, and are somewhat frowned upon for making answers harder to read.  Puzzling is somewhat different from other SE sites, so it might need different rules or policies.

Comment: Personally, I appreciate the spoilers, but I don't think it's a big deal if someone doesn't use them.

Answer (score 6):

Please don't flag these - we're just going to decline the flags using the following reason:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Since any user with editing privileges can handle the issue, there's nothing here that requires a moderator to take a look at it. Flags are reserved for issues which need or would be better handled by a moderator.

That being said, answers tend to have at least a few pairs of eyes on them, and someone's liable to pick it up and edit it if the OP doesn't. If nobody seems to want to step up, you can always post a link in chat. And if nobody edits it still, then... you can just move on. It's not a huge deal.

Comment: I see your point but I disagree (twofold). First of all, such thing is a moderator eligible because not everybody can edit, yet. Second, by not acting and just moving on, we're advocating passively deterioration of the site's quality. People will generally tend to do what's easiest and in the end, the site will get corrupted from within, I fear.

Comment: @KonradViltersten The solution to that is not to shunt the editing load off onto moderators. As much as I love the site, I'm already dedicating a lot of time to it, and if everyone flagged us for edits, I would probably not be able to (or, really, _want_ to) keep up. The solution to this comes from within: having participants who care about and are invested in the site's quality. (To be clear, moderators _can_ and _do_ edit - it's just not something _flags_ are good for.)

Comment: I see I wasn't clear. Let me rephrase. I want a mode to take a look at the answer and **delete** it, as it's harmful and definitely of no value in that context. It's incorrect and all the hints provided in it are already present in the other attempts. Hence, flag.

Comment: @KonradViltersten _Oh!_ I see what you're saying. Sorry, I thought from the flag that you wanted me to _edit_ the answer. My bad. But, even so, a downvote is what I'd suggest using for a harmful answer or answer of no value.